# Cost centres for Generic-derived instances?

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

According to `+RTS -p` time inherited, 90% of my execution time is spent running a `Generic` based `instance MyClass MyType` definitions, for a single class recursively over 100+ types/instances. I've tried getting GHC to tell me the details of that, to figure out which instances are slow, or which instances are called more often, so I can go and hand-optimize those.

However, I can't seem to get ghc to put cost centres on these functions even with `-fprof-auto-calls`.

What can I do to get call centres on each type class instance function, rather than just the whole top-level thing as one, so I know how much time is spent in each one?

Using ghc 9.2.4.

Comment: Come to think of it, if the type class usages aren't specialized, ther would just be one function, which takes a dict of functions as args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a typical generic function setup with a class for processing the representation whose instances do all the actual work:

```
class GSlow f where
  gslow :: f a -> Int
```

a separate type class for the generic function itself:

```
class Slow a where
  slow :: a -> Int
  default slow :: (Generic a, GSlow (Rep a)) => a -> Int
  slow = defaultSlow

defaultSlow :: (Generic a, GSlow (Rep a)) => a -> Int
defaultSlow = gslow . from
```

an instance for fields `K1` that passes control from one data type to the other:

```
instance Slow c => GSlow (K1 i c) where
  gslow (K1 x) = ... slow x ...
```

and a whole bunch of empty instances for your 100+ data types:

```
instance Slow Type1
instance Slow Type2
etc.
```

then, by far, the easiest thing to do is to search and replace your empty `instance Slow`s with:

```
instance Slow Type1 where slow = defaultSlow
instance Slow Type2 where slow = defaultSlow
```

With `-fprof-auto`, you should get a call center for every type-specific `slow = defaultSlow` function which should allow you to attribute the work in the `GSlow` instances to individual data types.